# OLEDB SELECT TOP 1 / MAX() only returning 4 digits

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Guys I'm doing a query to DB using [OLEDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722784(v=vs.85).aspx) with the following [Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
OleDbCommand maxCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id AS maxId FROM `tableName` ORDER BY id DESC", AppConstants.OLEDBCONNECTION);
```

And then printing the result:

```
maxCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataReader reader = maxCommand.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
Int64 maxId = Int64.Parse(reader["maxId"].ToString()) + 1;
```

The thing is I've tried using `MAX()` and `TOP 1` but both of them are returning 9999, when I know there are more than 10000 `id` values.

Help please, if you need any additional information please leave a comment.

Comment: What result do you get when you run the query directly on the database?

Comment: For several reasons I cannot run the query directly on the database sorry @Siyual But when I use the same process to search by `id` with `id=10001` I get a record

Comment: Then how do you know there are ids greater then 10000?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri If I query `SELECT * FROM tercli WHERE id=10001` I get a record so it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type of your `id` column is not `int`. It's probably a `varchar` column containing numbers. When you sort it, it's sorted in lexical order, not numeric.

To get the results you expect you can cast it to `int` (it won't be able to use index seek, so it will not be very efficient)

```
select max(cast (id as int)) ...
```

If it's possible, you should change the column type to `int`.

Comment: Yes you're right, the Data Type is `OleDbType.Char`, but how can I still get the highest value? i.e. the highest number?

Comment: @VítorMartins You can cast it to int: `select max(cast (id as int)) ...`, although it won't be very efficient. If it's possible, change the column type to int.